# Why can't I get my partial to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following a Rails tutorial, and I can't get my `_error_messages.html.erb` partial to render. It should show errors on the signup page when "submit" is clicked, and the form is blank. Instead I get:

```
partial users/user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/hmumin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
```

I don't get why it is searching for a partial user when it's supposed to be searching for the `_error_message.html.erb` partial.

My user controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
def new
@user = User.new
 end
def create
@user = User.new(user_params) #not the final implemention!
if @user.save
    #handle a successful save
else
    render new
end
  end

    private

def  user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,     :password_confirmation)
end
 end
```

sign-up page is:

```
    <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My error_messages partial is:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i got it, the issue was the user controller where i said render new as oppose to render 'new'.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the file _error_messages.html.erb is in the right folder. wich is:

app/views/shared